# Faye server not started by foreman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, faye, foreman

I am trying to start faye with foreman. My procfile lookd like this:

```
web: bundle exec rails server thin -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV
worker: bundle exec sidekiq
redis: bundle exec redis-server
faye: bundle exec rackup faye.ru -s thin -E production
```

When I run `bundle exec foreman start`

the web, worker and redis servers all start correctly, but not the faye server.

In the console I get: `10:53:56 faye.1   | started with pid 10907`

and then nothing more from faye.

If I run the faye server using the command in the procfile: `bundle exec rackup faye.ru -s thin -E production`, faye starts correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi there, what was your chosen solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run this locally:

```
bundle exec rackup faye.ru -s thin -E production
```

`rackup` will use it's default port, which is 9292.

When it's run on Herkou, it may not start if that port is already in use. Heroku dynamically assigns the `$PORT` variable to a valid free port as far as I am aware.

My guess is that Faye is either starting on a different port or not starting at all.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like faye is running OK. Try to visit `http://localhost:{PORT}/faye.js` to see if it's responding. It should come back with JS. Make sure you use the right port when calling faye server. Once you start making requests you should see faye logs being spit by foreman.

Answer (score 0):

This is Foreman's [missing output](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/wiki/Missing-Output) issue.

> If you are not seeing any output from your program, there is a likely chance that it is buffering `stdout`. Many languages such as Ruby and Python buffer `stdout` by default.

Faye doesn't set `$stdout.sync = true` and therefore its output is missing.

I've had the same issue some time ago and tried to fix it but my [pull request](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/pull/202) was rejected.